# App is crashing when setClassName is used to specify intents in

Tags: android, android-intent

Why is this code crashing ? It works fine when i use it as
 " intent i = new intent( this, activity_B); "

Here 'b' is the button which has an OnClickListener and 'c' is the activity to opened.

```
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("example.main",".c");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Specify full package name with class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setClassName take a Package Context as first param and Class as second param `setClassName(Context packageContext, String className)`

 you have to give it correctly like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.example.pkg1", "com.example.pkg1.Act1");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), so in your case what you need to do is:

```
i.setClassName(applicationId,"example.main.c");
```

where applicationId is a component name of your app (basically a package name which you declared for your app in gradle/manifest config)